# Devise current_user is sometimes lost after coming back from payment site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My app flow is:

- sign up (using a custom form), which also logs the user in
- redirection to payment website
- payment website redirects back to the Rails app
- sometimes, the `current_user` property is nil

95% of the time the flow works, but sometimes I get an error for some users that it does not work.

What would cause it to be not saved?

To `login`, I'm using the following code in my controller:

```
sign_in @user
```

Comment: What does the log say? Do you have an example of the log of the request when `current_user` is nil? Obviously devise is resetting the session but the log should give a hint of why it happens

Comment: Hey did you get aroudn this issue ? and how? Can you share your solution? I am facing similar problem